# Is there a standard way to state that white space is significant in a single XML element?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, dtd

Sometimes, when parsing XML into PHP's DOMDocument and outputting with `formatOutput=true`, white space will be introduced between XML tags where it's not wanted.

For example:

```
<td><i>lorem</i><b>ipsum</b></td>
```

becomes this, which adds white space between the two words:

```
<td>
    <i>lorem</i>
    <b>ipsum</b>
</td>
```

One way to work around this is to manually add a zero-width space at the end of the element, so that the parser treats the contents of the element as mixed content:

```
<td><i>lorem</i><b>ipsum</b>&#8203;</td>
```

There's also the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute, which is supposed to make the parser treat all white space as significant, but it doesn't seem to have any effect in this case:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<td xml:space="preserve"><i>lorem</i><b>ipsum</b></td>');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
print $dom->saveXML();

/* Output:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<td xml:space="preserve">
  <i>lorem</i>
  <b>ipsum</b>
</td>
*/
```

Is there a way (perhaps using the DTD) to tell the XML parser/writer that certain tags (`<i>` and `<b>` in this case) represent inline elements and that white space between them is important, or to manually mark specific elements as containing mixed content?

Comment: Adding CDATA just means that the angle brackets get interpreted as text, and get escaped on output: `<td>&lt;i&gt;lorem&lt;/i&gt;&lt;b&gt;ipsum&lt;/b&gt;</td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring the element as having mixed content (elements and `#PCDATA`). You'd have to do this at the `td` level though and not the `i` or `b` level.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE td [
<!ELEMENT td (#PCDATA|i|b)*>
<!ELEMENT i (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)>
]>
<td><i>lorem</i><b>ipsum</b></td>
```

I did not try this in PHP.

Comment: Using the same code as above but with the DTD added as in this answer, plus the LIBXML_DTDLOAD option for loadXML, it still produced the output with added white space as before. The declaration that mixed content *can* be there doesn't seem to make the element be treated as if mixed content *is* there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want whitespace to be significant, why on earth are you using `formatOutput=true`?!  Stop hitting yourself in the nose, and your nose may eventually stop bleeding.

Comment: I'd like the output to be pretty-printed, with appropriate indentation (the source XML is quite poorly indented). White space is not significant at the document level, but is (if possible) in certain elements.